# find the grammar for the language that contains all and only the words that have the form: $(a ... b c (b) (c c) b ) (a (c b) c ... a (b) a b)$

Tags: context-free-grammar

Give a context-free grammar for the language,with $\Sigma=\{(,),a,b,c\}$,that contains all and only the words that have the following form: $(a ... b c (b) (c c) b ) (a (c b) c ... a (b) a b)$ ,that is a text with balanced parenthesis,that contains any subwords of the symbols $a,b,c$ between any pair of matching parenthesis and only there-(for example the word $(a)b(c)$ is not allowed,because of the appearance of $b$).

Comment: can you standardize your notation, for example what is "..."?

Comment: that it can be any sequence of $a,b,c$,but it should be between any pair of matching parenthesis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a grammar for your language:

$\begin{array}{l}
S\to SS|(T)\\
T\to (T)|TT|A\\
A\to aA|bA|cA|\epsilon.
\end{array}
$

Comment: could you explain me why you put two $S$ at the first rule and two $T$ at the second?

Comment: if there is only one S, you cannot produce (a)(a). And if there is only one T, you cannot produce ((a)(a)). This allows to duplicate both the root expression and the inside expressions.

Comment: I understand..and something else is this rule $S \to \varnothing$ allowed or not?

Comment: And..with these rules,can we just have two pairs of parenthesis like that (()) or can it also be ((()))?

Comment: Yes you can add a rule $S\to \epsilon$ if you want the empty word in your language. You can derive $S\to (T)\to ((T))\to (((T)))\to(((A)))\to((()))$, because $T$ can unfold as many times as you want.

Comment: I understand...thank you very much!!!